# Detected when change page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a firstPage with BottomNavigationBar with 3 screens.

I want to detect when I change page from **BottomNavigationBar** inside a specific page, because when I leave this page, I must to execute a function contained inside this page.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to create 3 boolean global variables(one for each page in the BottomNavigationBar) and initialize it to false. When the user goes to the second page from the first page set one of the boolean variables to true. Then check if that variable is true and execute your function. Be sure to set the variable back to false when the user leaves the page. Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes, but I need to call a function contained in one of this 3 pages from BottomNavigationBar

Comment: Here is another way to go about this. Create a global variable that holds an integer from 0,1,2,3 values. 0 is your main page, 1 being your first page, 2 being second, and so on and so forth. So you switch screens from the second page to the first, you know that the value of the global variable is 2 as that's the last page the user visited. When the user reaches the first page from the second, first call the method that you have on the second page then change the global variable value to 1. Does that make sense?